# Application icon badge number is not changing to zero on launching the application by touching the app icon

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I am developing a local notification code . I am being able to display the badge number as per the number of notifications fired and also I am able to make all the icons to 0 when user opens the notification,But if the user launches the app the badge is not set to 0. It is only set to 0 when user opens the notification. I have read multiple answers & multiple articles and couldn't find a solution . In order to register my local notification I have the following code -

```
func addItem(item: TodoItem)
    {
        // persist a representation of this todo item in NSUserDefaults

        var todoDictionary = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey(ITEMS_KEY) ?? Dictionary()// if todoItems hasn't been set in user defaults, initialize todoDictionary to an empty dictionary using nil-coalescing operator (??)

        todoDictionary[item.UUID] = ["deadline" : item.deadline, "title" : item.title, "UUID" : item.UUID]// store NSData representation of todo item in dictionary with UUID as key

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(todoDictionary, forKey: ITEMS_KEY)

        let notification  = UILocalNotification()

        notification.alertBody = "Todo Item \"\(item.title)\" Is Overdue" // text that will be displayed in the notification
        notification.alertAction = "open" // text that is displayed after "slide to..." on the lock screen - defaults to "slide to view"
        notification.fireDate = item.deadline // todo item due date (when notification will be fired)
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName // play default sound
        notification.userInfo = ["title": item.title, "UUID": item.UUID] // assign a unique identifier to the notification so that we can retrieve it later
       let nextbadge = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications?.count)! + 1
        notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = nextbadge//here I provide an incremental badge number to my local notification.
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)


    }
```

In my appdelagate class

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification)
    {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("ToDoListShouldtRefresh", object: self)

         application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;


    }
```

Now in objective C I was usually doing like this to clear badges on application launch -

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Handle launching from a notification
    UILocalNotification *locationNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    if (locationNotification) {
        // Set icon badge number to zero
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

I tried something like this but with vain -

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
    {


        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings (forTypes:[.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil))
        if let notification:UILocalNotification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey] as? UILocalNotification
        {

            application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
        }
        return true





    }
```

So how to do it now in SWIFT?

Answer (score 0):

**UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey** will be set only if user opens app via notification.

So, if you need to set applicationIconBadgeNumber to 0 right after launch in all cases, you need no check for **UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey**:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings (forTypes:[.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil))
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    return true

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to think if opening the app without clicking the notification will allow the user to see that he has available the notification content. And what if he has many of them?

If the user can see the content or events of all of the notifications at once, you can set applicationIconBadgeNumber to 0 every time the app becomes active, or you might keep decreasing it only when the user gets to click or see the content.

So I would do it on applicationDidBecomeActive so it also sets it to 0 if the app was in background.

`func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
}`

Answer (score -1):

no problem with applicationIconBadgeNumber. the problem is with localnotification. addobserver and name to localnotification

Comment: Sorry can you clarify a bit more.